# Programming MSP430 with Raspberry PI 2

Tags: i2c, spi

So I am trying to give instructions to my MSP430G2553, to blink a led for example. There are some IDEs for programming the chip over USB, but i want to use my raspberry to program it directly through some interface.
I want to program the chip directly only using jumper wires and clean C using the mspdebug and msp compiler which we can get from Texas Instruments.

So what interface should i use?

- Can I use common communication interfaces like  I2C or SPI for example?
- Or should i use JTAG?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Energia](http://energia.nu/) which brings an Arduino like environment to the Ti Launchpad MSP430 series.

I haven't personally used the Energia environment on the Pi, but neither have I used the Arduino IDE on the Pi.

I have used both the Energia and Arduino IDEs from other Linux boxes.

Comment: Thanks! But i would like to program the chip directly only using jumper wires and clean C using the mspdebug  and msp compiler which we can get from Texas Instruments.

Comment: @AleksanderDashov Perhaps you should add that information to your question so people are not misled.